# Is Orbit Criterion an abstract nonsense? Different induced fundamental groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

> **(Orbit Criterion)** Let $p:\tilde X \to X$ be a covering map. If $\tilde q, \tilde q' \in \tilde X$ are two points in the same fiber $p^{-1}(q)$, there exists a covering transformation taking $\tilde q$ to $\tilde q '$ if and only if the induced subgroups $p_{*}\pi_{1}(\tilde X, \tilde q)$ and $p_{*}\pi_{1}(\tilde X, \tilde q')$ are equal.

It is well known lemma in a covering group theory, however I am wondering about example of some neat covering space with different induced fundamental groups $p_{*}\pi_{1}(\tilde X, \tilde q)$ and $p_{*}\pi_{1}(\tilde X, \tilde q')$ (where $\tilde q, \tilde q '$ are in the same fiber). I used so far only very ordinary covering spaces so I cannot come up with such example and hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a circle. Let $p : \widetilde X \to X$ be the universal cover, where $\widetilde X$ is a line. It follows that $X \sqcup \widetilde X$ with the obvious map is a covering space of $X$ that satisfies the property you're looking for. Just pick $\tilde q \in X$, $\tilde q' \in \widetilde X$.

If you want a path-connected covering space, consider the $2$-oriented graph $X$ whose fundamental group is the free group on two generators $\langle a, b\rangle$. The subgroup $\langle a\rangle$ is not a normal subgroup of $\langle a, b\rangle$, and hence the covering space $\widetilde X$ that corresponds to $\langle a\rangle$ is also not normal. Let $q$ be the base point of $X$. Depending on the choice of $\tilde q$, the subgroup $p_*(\pi_1(\widetilde X, \tilde q))$ will have the form $\langle b^i ab^{-i}\rangle$ for some fixed $i$. Here is a visualization of $\widetilde X$ (courtesy of [Hatcher's Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html)):

[image: Covering space]

Comment: The second part is clear for me (Thanks for an answer!) but I don't understand the first one. You mean cannonical covering $p(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$, do you? Please elaborate how you choose these points $\tilde q, \tilde q'$. (In fact I forgot to mention that $\tilde q, \tilde q'$ lies in the same fiber - but yours $S^1 \vee S^1$ covering seems to fulfill this assumption.)

Comment: @108592 Both examples fulfill the assumption you have. In the first example, let the covering space $Y$ be the disjoint union of a circle and line. The circle is mapped to $X$ via the identity map. The line is mapped to $X$ via the map $p(x) = e^{2\pi ix}$ as you suggest. The pre-image of a point of $X$ is the union of infinitely many points from the line and one point from the circle. If you choose $\tilde q$ from the circle and $\tilde q'$ from the line (both on the same fiber), then $p_*(\pi_1(Y, \tilde q))$ is infinite cyclic, whereas $p_*(\pi_1(Y, \tilde q'))$ is trivial.

Comment: OK, now I understand what you mean!